# Using function as an instance method with Enthought Traits (Python)

Tags: python, lambda, traitsui

I would like to create an instance method based on a function, as a parameter to 
instance initialization, as follows:

```
from traits.api import *

class C(HasTraits):
    f = Function

c = C(f=lambda self: self)
```

However, if I run

```
c.f()
```

it says (not in any way surprisingly)

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Changing f from Function to Method does not help as it does not accept the function 
argument (requires instancemethod).

So my question is, how I could get custom function act as instance method (with self parameter as ordinary instance methods) when using Traits?

Comment: First, there is no such thing as a 'lambda function". `lambda` and `def` both define the exact same kind of thing—a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define new Trait type MyMethod as follows:

```
import types
class MyMethod(TraitType):
    def validate(self, object, name, value): 
        if isinstance(value, types.MethodType):
            return value
        if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType):
            return types.MethodType(value, object, object.__class__)
        self.error(object, name, value)
```

and use it instead of Function or Method in the previous code, and functions will be converted to instancemethods automatically.

Comment: One comment: you should not use `type(foo) == bar`; use `is instance(foo, bar)` instead. This doesn't matter too much for functions and methods (because, at least in CPython, they can't be subclassed or ABC'd), but it's still a good habit to get in, and makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

A function—whether defined with `lambda` or `def`—is not a method.

You can't just change its type; a method has more information in it than a function—it's bound to an object. That's how Python knows what to pass for the first (`self`) parameter.

In your case, you're looking for an *unbound method*, which isn't bound to an *object*—but it's still bound to a *class*.

In normal cases (when you `def` a method inside a `class` definition, then create an instance of the class, then call a method on it), this happens automatically for you. (See [How methods work](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-methods-work.html) for some details.) But when you're doing it all yourself, you need to create the bound method yourself.

As with any other type in Python, you do this by calling the type as a constructor. The problem is that "bound method" isn't accessible as a builtin type. That means you have to go to the [`types`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#module-types) module, which "defines names for some object types that are used by the standard Python interpreter". Like this:

```
bound = types.MethodType(func, my_obj, type(my_obj))

unbound = types.UnboundMethodType(func, None, my_type)
```

---

But notice that there's often no good reason to do this—you could just as easily cram the object into the closure. These callables will all do the same thing:

```
func = lambda self: self
bound = types.MethodType(func, my_obj, type(my_obj))

func2 = lambda: my_obj

func3 = lambda self: self
unbound = types.UnboundMethodType(func, None, my_type)
func3a = lambda: unbound(my_obj)
```

---

Two last thoughts:

If you understand about [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), the magic that makes `@property` work and the magic that makes bound methods work will interfere with each other. I don't know if that's true with Enthough traits, but it might. So, the answer to your question could well turn out to be "you can't do that". Instead, you will have to create a `Function` trait, and then a wrapper method that calls that trait explicitly.

If you use Python 3.x instead of 2.x, unbound methods go away (classes just use plain old functions), so a lot of the complexity you're hitting never arises.

Comment: It seems that Traits is not yet working with Python 3. In my case I can change f from function to instancemethod by using MethodType in constructor. Or better: by defining type validation to return types.MethodType(value, object, object.__class__) (I will edit this further to my original question).

Comment: @TuomasA.: Since my answer explained all the details, but not how to actually _solve_ the problem (Enthought's docs pages seem to be broken at the moment…), you might want to write and accept your own answer. (You can still upvote mine without accepting it, if you have the rep to do it.) If you don't want to do that, and would rather I copy your solution into my answer, I can, but really it's your work, and you deserve the credit.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote up. Anyway, your suggestion about using types.MethodType was essential. Thanks. Moreover I can't accept my own answer yet (it says after 2 days I can do it).

Comment: @TuomasA.: No problem; I'm sure anyone coming here with the same problem as you who doesn't understand your answer will see mine directly underneath it, so everything is fine without the upvote.